# How to hide utm-marks with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, utm

**Situation:** Google.Adwords ads with links with many utm-marks.

**Problem:** when user come to my site from ad-link, he sees long creepy url with utm (`http://site.org?utm_source=xxx&utm_medium=xxx#anchorname` and so on); I want him to see short site url (`http://site.org#ankorname`).

**Thoughts:** theoretically, I can do redirect from any link with `?utm` to link without `?utm` (clear everything after `?`). But, sometimes, there are some anchors in the end of the links (`#anchorname`), so I don't want to delete it.

**Question:** how to make redirect rules, to redirect utm-link to none-utm-link, saving anchors, and do it in specific Google.Analytics way (I want analytics see utm-marks before link will be cleared).